# combinatorics dice question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, dice

There are $10$ identical dice ($1$ - $6$).
How many different results can we get so that the set of results will be exactly $3$.
for example: $7$ dice will be the number $2$, $2$ dice will be $3$ and the last die will be $6$ so the set of results is $\{2,3,6\}$.

We are arguing here over the answer, I think that the answer is 
$$\frac{6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3^7}{2}$$
while my friend strongly suggests that we will have to use the inclusion - exclusion principle. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by “different results”? If the numbers $1$, $2$, and $3$ come up as $(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3)$, is that a different result than $(1,2,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,3)$ or $(1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)$? In any case, why don’t you see whose method works if there are four dice instead of ten? Or see what you get for three dice, trying to count the results where exactly two different numbers come up?

Answer (score 3):

if the order  does not matter:first select the three numbers you want to appear in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways. Once this has been done you want to divide the ten results into three groups. To do this use stars and bars, there are $10$ stars, and $2$ bars. But since every part needs at least one star there are really $7$ stars and so the answer is $\binom{9}{2}$

Hence you want $\binom{6}{2}\binom{9}{2}$.

---

If order matters: What you want to count is functions from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ that have a range with three elements. There are $\binom{6}{3}$, once you have selected the range you want to count the number of surjective functions from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ to that range. to do this apply the twelvefold method. The answer is $3! {10 \brace 3}$. Hence the final answer is $\binom{6}{3}3!{10\brace3}$.

Note $\binom{n}{k}$ is the binomial coefficient and $n\brace k$ is the stirling coefficient of the second kind..

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation assumes that the first three dice have different values.  The factor $6$ says the first can be anything, the $5$ says the second has to be different from the first, the $4$ says the third has to be different from the first two.  The $3^7$ says each other die can be any of the three numbers.  I don't understand the division by $2$. Following this logic you should divide by $6$ because the first three numbers can come in any order.  You have missed rolls like $1111223333$ because the first three dice are the same.

I would use inclusion/exclusion.  You can select the three numbers in ${6 \choose 3}=20$ ways.  Then we want to find the number of $10$ digit strings from $1,2,3$ that include at least one of each number.  There are $3^{10}$ strings total, then we subtract the $3 \cdot 2^{10}$ that have only two different digits, then add the $3$ that have a single digit.  The final answer is ${6 \choose 3}(3^{10}-3\cdot 2^{10}+3)=1,119,600$

Comment: The number of ways to choose $3$ out of $6$ possible results is $\binom63=20$. The number of ways to divide $10$ dice into $3$ groups is $\binom92=36$. The number of ways to assign $3$ results to $3$ groups is $3!=6$. So the total number of combinations is $20\cdot36\cdot6=4320$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: That inclusion exclusion is precisely the idea that is used to prove ${n \brace k}= \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^{k-j}{k \choose j} j^n$ if one wishes to do so combinatorially

Comment: @barakmanos:  you are counting the number without regard to order, though then you shouldn't multiply by the final $6$.  OP seems to count different orders as different, based on the logic I give in my first paragraph.